# c# Sorting a list based on number

Tags: sorting, c#-3.0

I have a list of fields which a user can sort using jquery. I save these updated fields in the database. The same fields can be added and removed from the report, so in some cases I will have `field1, field55, field 3`. The fields can appear in a random order (based on where it appears in the report).

I am trying to sort a list where in most cases the field will have a value but it can also be 0.

```
var list = Dictionary<string,int>(); //loaded from the client side, in-memory
```

I have a list where I use the method `list.orderby(x=> x.Value);` This will sort fields in the correct order, however I want to get the remaining fields whos order = 0, and append to the end of the list with the **greatest** number in the list.

e.g. the highest number in the list is 78, I have 4 fields that have the prop Order = 0, these fields should be 79,80,81,82 respectively.

Something like this may work, but I am getting a collection modified error:

```
        var max = list.Max(x => x.Value);

        foreach (var item in list.Where(x => x.Value == 0))
        {
            list[item.Key] = ++max;
        }
```

Comment: I assume that you are getting the list items from a DB, wouldn't it be better to sort them in SQL?

Comment: In-memory query, the database call is afterwards, I only want the database ids that match the ids the user has selected otherwise I will have a *massive* query back... I am just doing the sorting whilst I am accessing this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        {"Banana", 123},
        {"Apple", 234},
        {"Orange", 34},
        {"Pear", 4},
        {"Elephant", 99},
        {"UnOrderedItem1", 0},
        {"UnOrderedItem2", 0},
        {"UnOrderedItem3", 0},
        {"UnOrderedItem4", 0},
    };

int nextValue = list.Max(x => x.Value) + 1;
var elementsWithZero = (from l in list where l.Value == 0 select l)
    .ToList();

foreach (var item in elementsWithZero)
{
    list[item.Key] = nextValue++;
}

var sortedList = (from l in list select l)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Value);

foreach (var item in sortedList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Value, item.Key);
}
```

Output:

```
4: Pear
34: Orange
99: Elephant
123: Banana
234: Apple
235: UnOrderedItem1
236: UnOrderedItem2
237: UnOrderedItem3
238: UnOrderedItem4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could order the records that don't have order=0 first, then append or union the order=0 records to that collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can create own Comparer like this

```
list.OrderBy(new FieldDTOComparer());

private class FieldDTOComparer : IComparer<FieldDTO>
{
    public int Compare(FieldDTO x, FieldDTO y)
    {
        if (x.Order == 0)
            return 1;
        if (y.Order == 0)
            return -1;
        return x.Order - y.Order;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (untested):

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(x => x.Value);
var nextValue = list.Max(x => x.Value) + 1;

foreach (var item in sortedList.Where(x => x.Value == 0))
{
    item.Value = nextValue;
    nextValue++;
}
```